# What causes the difference in time between these methods when reading files in different ways on python

Tags: python

I recently tried to compare different methods of reading text files on Python, and this is the code I used to compare these methods.

```py
def read_file(file_name: str) -> None:
    """Read the file with different methods."""

    def method_read(method: Callable) -> None:
        t_start = time.time()
        with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
            res = method(f)
        print(f'{method.__name__:>20s} took {(time.time() - t_start) * 1000:.2f} ms, result: {res[:3]}')

    def read_then_split(f):
        return f.read().splitlines(keepends=True)

    def line_for_line(f):
        return [line for line in f]
    
    def readlines(f):
        return f.readlines()

    def line_for_readlines(f):
        return [line for line in f.readlines()]

    method_read(read_then_split)     # 1
    method_read(line_for_line)       # 2
    method_read(readlines)           # 3
    method_read(line_for_readlines)  # 4
```

Here are the results.

```bash
     read_then_split took 253.21 ms, result: ['00000001\n', '00000002\n', '00000003\n']
       line_for_line took 545.94 ms, result: ['00000001\n', '00000002\n', '00000003\n']
           readlines took 461.51 ms, result: ['00000001\n', '00000002\n', '00000003\n']
  line_for_readlines took 716.66 ms, result: ['00000001\n', '00000002\n', '00000003\n']
```

I can understand the difference between method 1 and the subsequent methods. I know this is because method 1 reads the file into memory in one time.

But what causes the difference between the three subsequent methods? Especially method 2 and method 3, it seems to me that they are almost indistinguishable.

Update:

I am reading a txt file with 1e7 lines, the first line is 00000001 and the last line is 10000000.

I used python 3.10 to run it on a MacBook Air with an m1 chip.

Here is the code to generate the file:

```py
def readable_size(size: int) -> str:
    """Return a human readable size."""
    for unit in ['B', 'KB', 'MB', 'GB', 'TB']:
        if size < 1024:
            return f'{size:.2f} {unit}'
        size /= 1024
    return f'{size:.2f} PB'

def generate_file(num_lines: int, file_name: str) -> None:
    """Generate a file with the given number of lines."""
    t_start = time.time()
    num_digits = len(str(num_lines))
    strf = f'0{num_digits}d'
    file_content = '\n'.join([str(format(i + 1, strf)) for i in range(num_lines)])
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        f.write(file_content)
    print(f'{num_lines} lines written to {file_name}, {time.time() - t_start:.2f} seconds')
    print(f'size of file {file_name}: {readable_size(os.path.getsize(file_name))}')
```

Comment: I just tested it and for me the differences are negligible other than `line_for_readlines` which is likely due to creating 2 `list` s rather than 1.

Comment: When I run this code, my run times are not anywhere near as long.  On what machine did you run this code?  Did that machine have lots of other jobs also running?

Comment: @JohnGordon The file is probably much larger. Only the first 3 lines are being printed. `res[:3]`.

Comment: I have updated my test environment and the code that generates the text file in the question. At the same time I also closed all other programs and ran the code several times. The read times do not fluctuate very much, and the difference between them is still very significant.